# Draggable is not dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

Somehow my draggables arn't dragging anymore into the placeholders.

I noticed it gives an error on the `appendChild` in the `drop()` function but when I alert in there I notice it doesn't even get that far.

```js
var people = ['Sinan', 'Babette', 'Thomas', 'Yannick', 'Nick'];
$.each(people, function(key, val) {
  $('#placeholders').append('<div class="dnd" data-id="' + val + '" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="testDiv(event, innerHTML)"></div>');
});

$('#seizeImg img').on('dragstart', function(event) {
  drag(event);
});

function testDiv(ev, x) {
  if (x.length > 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    allowDrop(ev);
    return true;
  }
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

  var complete = false;
  $.each('#seizeImg img', function(key, val) {
    alert(key);
  });
}
```

```css
.dnd {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 10%;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #B7E6E6;
  background: rgba(51, 255, 102, 0.2);
}

#seizeImg img {
  width: 10%;
  height: 160px;
}

div.label {
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

div.buf {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="placeholders">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="seizeImg">
  <img id="Babette" src="img/Babette.jpg" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" width="186" height="186">
  <img id="Thomas" src="img/Thomas.jpg" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" width="186" height="186">
  <img id="Yannick" src="img/Yannick.jpg" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" width="186" height="186">
  <img id="Sinan" src="img/Sinan.jpg" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" width="186" height="186">
  <img id="Nick" src="img/Nick.jpg" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" width="186" height="186">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using jqueryUI with the drag and drop libraries installed. If you aren't that might make things a little easier for you.

you could make it work with:

```
$('#seizeImg img').draggable();
```

and if you wanted the drop to save data all you have to do is:

```
 $('#placeholders').droppable({
accept: $('#seizeImg img'),
drop: function(){
//enter code here to take place whenever you drop something on it
// if you want to take a value from the object you are dropping on
// the droppable object just use:
var varID = (ui.draggable.attr("value");
    }
});
```

Its a little more concise and jqueryUI takes out a lot of the guess work.

**EDIT:**
Unless you didn't include the code up top, you never call the actual jqueryUI draggable function.  somewhere around

```
  $(document).ready({function(){   
     // you have to include 
$('seizeImg img').draggable({function(){ 
    //add some more moving parts here if you need to
    });   
 }
```

just setting draggable='true' in your HTML isn't the same thing.

Comment: Yea I did that but it still says that the draggable function is not found. But the main problem was that there was a layer over the draggables that was keeping me from clicking it.. I have worked hours on this problem and apparently it's just some stupid layer

Comment: If you have gotten to where you can click on it and drag it but still are having issues with layers you can always in:  $('seizeImg img').draggable({function(){ //add function here}, //right here  you can add stack: "seizeImg img", appendTo: "body", zIndex: 10000}); and it will make what every you start dragging the topmost item.

Comment: Yea I reduced the z-index of the layer above it

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is caused by the lines below

```
 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

You are trying to append an element that is not of `Node` type. That is happening because `data` is an empty string thus `document.getElementById("")` returns `null` which is not allowed to be passued to `appendChild`.

Comment: Yea I noticed dataTransfer in side ev doesn't exist but why? This same code does work on an earlier version